# Disable file integrity check on Linux NAS server (WD MyCloud Ex41)

Tags: linux, apache, vhosts

I have a Linux NAS server  **(WD MyCloud Ex41)** that I want to create an aditional apache2 vhost on it. Now the problem every time I create a new vhost file and when i reboot the server my vhost that i created will lost and back to its original config. With that said, I think the OS has performing the file integrity checking during boot or so. Is there a way to disable this, or maybe create a config file during boot at runs/execute the new config file it after the integrity checking? or maybe on bash script? Please advise. Thanks

Comment: There is nothing we can say, since you keep your question generic... "A Linux NAS"... How do you expect us to help with such vague information

Comment: I edited it for you.

Comment: A simple search on google for those terms delivered a wealth of results explaining how to do that. Also some links to the official forum. None of that helped for you?

Comment: I did, but no luck, that's why I tried to ask here.

Comment: I fail to find _any_ trace of such a watchdog feature as you describe in any of the documentations of forum topics. I suspect that either your reboot includes an update (automatic) which indeed _may_ replace the files or that your system reinstalls itself with every reboot due to a broken battery or something like that. But a normal WD myCloud system does _not_ show the behavior you describe.

Comment: I suggest you ask your question in their forum.